# Laravel mail keeps sending mail to hello@example.org

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some issues with the Mailables from laravel, I am trying to send a simple mail from a controller method to a given email address like so:

`Mail::to('demo@example.org')->send(new ContactMail($data));`

To me the seems exactly like the docs state:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#sending-mail

But this does not seem to work for me, the mail keeps being send to `hello@example.org` (or whatever I provide in the mail config file).

I am expecting the mail to be send to the mail i'm proving in the `to()` method, is there anything i'm missing

The mailable:

```
class ContactMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $contactMailData)
    {
        $this->viewData = $contactMailData;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->viewData['subject'])
            ->from($this->viewData['email'])
            ->view('mailables.contact', $this->viewData);
    }
}
```

Already tried to clear the config and cache, which had no effect.

Comment: @aynber `Mail` facade has `to` method. it represents from \Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail

Comment: Never mind. I was looking at your code block, not at your command at the top.

Comment: Did you check your error.log file is there any error or not? and did you properly set your .env file for sending mail?

Comment: @HashemiRafsan the mail driver is set to the log, so no errors. The mail gets send but to the wrong address.

Comment: You can try again after clear the cache. `php artisan cache:clear` .
Though if not working then re-check from where you call `Mail::to($email)->send(new ContactMail($data));`

Comment: @HashemiRafsan already tried that, did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to the problem is actually quite simple, the `config/mail.php` has a default where all mails are being send to.

```php
    'to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_TO_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
```

I thought that if i would use the `Mail::to('whateveremail@example.org')` method, this would override the default mail to settings provided in the `config/mail.php`.

But that does not happen, so the solution is turn of the default 'to' array in the `config/mail.php`.

When done, clear the config cache and the problem is solved.

```sh
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use Queueable, SerializesModels;
public $user ; 
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $user ,array $contactMailData  )
{
    $this->user =$user ;
    $this->viewData = $contactMailData;

    //
}



public function build()
{
 return $this->to($user->email)->subject($this->viewData['subject'])
        ->from($this->viewData['email'])
        ->view('mailables.contact', $this->viewData);
}
```

Comment: I do not have a user, but besides that this wont work.

Comment: can you show me from where you are calling (sending) mail  plz?